# Shortening distance between node and "pin" in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why is the distance between the labels for points `Q` and `R` so far from the "pins" in the following diagram?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%The slope-intercept form for the line k is y = 2x - 6, and the slope-intercept form for
%the line $\ell$ is y = -x + 8. The two lines intersect at (8/3, 16/3). Point Q = (4/3, -10/3)
%is on line k, and point R = (8/3, 16/3) is on line $\ell$. (The diagram is magnified by 1/2.)
\draw[<->] ({(1/2)*(-3/2)},{(1/2)*(-9)}) -- ({(1/2)*15/2},{(1/2)*9});
\node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($({(1/2)*15/2},{(1/2)*9}) +({atan(2)}:0.15)$){$\ell$};
\draw[<->] ({(1/2)*(-1)},{(1/2)*9}) -- ({(1/2)*19/2},{(1/2)*(-3/2)});
\node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($({(1/2)*19/2},{(1/2)*(-3/2)}) +({atan(-1)}:0.15)$){\textit{k}};


%P, Q, and R are collinear. P is the midpoint of QR, Q is a point on $\ell$, and
%R is a point on k.
\coordinate (P) at ({(1/2)*2},{(1/2)*1});
\draw[fill] (P) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\coordinate (Q) at ({(1/2)*8/3},{(1/2)*16/3});
\draw[fill] (Q) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\coordinate (R) at ({(1/2)*4/3},{(1/2)*(-10/3)});
\draw[fill] (R) circle [radius=1.5pt];


%Point P is labeled.
\path let \p1=($(P)-(Q)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor={\n1-90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(P)!0.15cm!90:(Q)$){\textit{P}};


%The intersection of the two lines is labeled T, and "pins" are drawn to Q and R.
\coordinate (T) at ({(1/2)*14/3},{(1/2)*10/3});
%
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (Q) -- ($(Q)!0.5cm!90:(T)$);
\path let \p1=($(Q)-(T)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor={\n1-90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(Q)!0.5cm!90:(T)$){\textit{Q}};
%
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (R) -- ($(R)!0.5cm!-90:(T)$);
\path let \p1=($(R)-(T)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor={\n1+90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(R)!0.5cm!-90:(T)$){\textit{R}};


%The dashed line segment QR is drawn.
\draw[dashed] ({(1/2)*4/3},{(1/2)*(-10/3)}) -- ({(1/2)*8/3},{(1/2)*16/3});


%The axes are drawn.
\draw[latex-latex] ($(0,{(1/2)*(-9)})  +(0pt,-12.5pt)$) -- ($(0,{(1/2)*9})  +(0pt,12.5pt)$) node[above right]{$y$};
\draw[latex-latex] ($({(1/2)*(-3/2)},0) +(-12.5pt,0pt)$) -- ($({(1/2)*19/2},0) +(12.5pt,0pt)$) node[below right]{$x$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you've `shorten`ed the lines by 1mm, but not taken that into account when you placed the nodes.

Either remove `shorten >=1mm` where you draw the pins, or use `at ($(Q)!0.4cm!90:(T)$){\textit{Q}}` (note 0.4mm instead of the 0.5mm you had), and similar for the `R` node.

## More detail

So let's look at what happens if we add `draw,very thin` to the `Q` and `R` nodes:

[image][image]

The gap from the end of the pin to the node border is caused by `shorten >=1mm`, so if we remove that, we get:

[image][image]

The space within the node border is probably caused by the bounding box of the character itself, and as such has nothing to do with TikZ. If you need even less space, you can for example use a negative value for shorten, e.g. `shorten >=-2pt`, which gives you this:

[image][image]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%The slope-intercept form for the line k is y = 2x - 6, and the slope-intercept form for
%the line $\ell$ is y = -x + 8. The two lines intersect at (8/3, 16/3). Point Q = (4/3, -10/3)
%is on line k, and point R = (8/3, 16/3) is on line $\ell$. (The diagram is magnified by 1/2.)
\draw[<->] ({(1/2)*(-3/2)},{(1/2)*(-9)}) -- ({(1/2)*15/2},{(1/2)*9});
\node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($({(1/2)*15/2},{(1/2)*9}) +({atan(2)}:0.15)$){$\ell$};
\draw[<->] ({(1/2)*(-1)},{(1/2)*9}) -- ({(1/2)*19/2},{(1/2)*(-3/2)});
\node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($({(1/2)*19/2},{(1/2)*(-3/2)}) +({atan(-1)}:0.15)$){\textit{k}};


%P, Q, and R are collinear. P is the midpoint of QR, Q is a point on $\ell$, and
%R is a point on k.
\coordinate (P) at ({(1/2)*2},{(1/2)*1});
\draw[fill] (P) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\coordinate (Q) at ({(1/2)*8/3},{(1/2)*16/3});
\draw[fill] (Q) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\coordinate (R) at ({(1/2)*4/3},{(1/2)*(-10/3)});
\draw[fill] (R) circle [radius=1.5pt];


%Point P is labeled.
\path let \p1=($(P)-(Q)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor={\n1-90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(P)!0.15cm!90:(Q)$){\textit{P}};


%The intersection of the two lines is labeled T, and "pins" are drawn to Q and R.
\coordinate (T) at ({(1/2)*14/3},{(1/2)*10/3});
%
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=-2pt] (Q) -- ($(Q)!0.5cm!90:(T)$);
\path let \p1=($(Q)-(T)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[%draw,very thin, % uncomment to get border of node
anchor={\n1-90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(Q)!0.5cm!90:(T)$){\textit{Q}};
%
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=-2pt] (R) -- ($(R)!0.5cm!-90:(T)$);
\path let \p1=($(R)-(T)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[%draw,very thin, % uncomment to get border of node
anchor={\n1+90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(R)!0.5cm!-90:(T)$){\textit{R}};


%The dashed line segment QR is drawn.
\draw[dashed] ({(1/2)*4/3},{(1/2)*(-10/3)}) -- ({(1/2)*8/3},{(1/2)*16/3});


%The axes are drawn.
\draw[latex-latex] ($(0,{(1/2)*(-9)})  +(0pt,-12.5pt)$) -- ($(0,{(1/2)*9})  +(0pt,12.5pt)$) node[above right]{$y$};
\draw[latex-latex] ($({(1/2)*(-3/2)},0) +(-12.5pt,0pt)$) -- ($({(1/2)*19/2},0) +(12.5pt,0pt)$) node[below right]{$x$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With the code that I provided in my post, it seems that some space surrounding the `Q` and `R` is inserted.  I used `inner sep=0` as an option for the node command.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire I edited my post, does that make it clearer?

Comment: I appreciate your careful explanation and illustrations.  "The space within the node border is probably caused by the bounding box of the character itself."

Comment: I now understand that the distance between the "pin" and letter labeling the point is determined by the box containing the letter. An end of the "pin" can be drawn into this box by using `shorten >=-1pt` or `shorten >=-2pt`.